# 406 Not Acceptable error when rendering JSON from a gem (works in other parts of the app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to return JSON from a method within the Devise gem I'm modifying in a Rail 3.0.4 app.

I am already successfully returning JSON from other parts of the application as well as the same gem, but not this controller.

I've spent hours on this and have NO idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was editing the wrong gem file (someone had run bundler, didn't realize it)